# Android Facebook Authentication Failed to Launch- Cannot Find PlatformProvider

Tags: android, facebook, android-facebook

I am collaborating with someone on an Android application. My partner wrote a Facebook authentication/sharing process on her emulator, but it fails to launch on my computer. Here's the code:

```
package com.example.music23andme;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle; 
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

import com.facebook.*;
import com.facebook.widget.*;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
OnClickListener login23_listener = null;
OnClickListener music_listener = null;
OnClickListener loginfb_listener = null;
Button button_login23w;
Button button_musicw;
Button button_loginfbw;
Button button_demo;

private UiLifecycleHelper uiHelper;

private Session.StatusCallback callback = new Session.StatusCallback() {
    @Override
    public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
        onSessionStateChange(session, state, exception);
    }
};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    uiHelper = new UiLifecycleHelper(this, callback);
    uiHelper.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    login23_listener = new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent0 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, WebViewActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent0);
        }
    };
    music_listener = new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent1 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MusicActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent1);
        }
    };
    loginfb_listener = new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (FacebookDialog.canPresentShareDialog(getApplicationContext(), 
                    FacebookDialog.ShareDialogFeature.SHARE_DIALOG)) {
                FacebookDialog shareDialog = new FacebookDialog.ShareDialogBuilder(MainActivity.this)
                .setLink("https://developers.facebook.com/android")
                .build();
                uiHelper.trackPendingDialogCall(shareDialog.present());
            }
        }
    };
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    button_login23w = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_login23);
    button_login23w.setOnClickListener(login23_listener);
    button_musicw = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_music);
    button_musicw.setOnClickListener(music_listener);
    button_loginfbw = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_loginfb);
    button_loginfbw.setOnClickListener(loginfb_listener);
    button_demo= (Button) findViewById(R.id.playDemo);
    button_demo.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent demoIntent= new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MusicActivity.class);
            demoIntent.putExtra("demo", true);
            startActivity(demoIntent);
        }

    });
} 

private void onSessionStateChange(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
    if ((exception instanceof FacebookOperationCanceledException) ||
            (exception instanceof FacebookAuthorizationException)) {
            new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this)
                .setTitle(R.string.cancelled)
                .setMessage(R.string.permission_not_granted)
                .setPositiveButton(R.string.ok, null)
                .show();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    uiHelper.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data, new FacebookDialog.Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookDialog.PendingCall pendingCall, Exception error, Bundle data) {
            Log.e("Activity", String.format("Error: %s", error.toString()));
        }

        @Override
        public void onComplete(FacebookDialog.PendingCall pendingCall, Bundle data) {
            Log.i("Activity", "Success!");
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    uiHelper.onResume();
}

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    uiHelper.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    uiHelper.onPause();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    uiHelper.onDestroy();
}
```

}

The error message was:

> Failed to find provider info for com.facebook.katana.provider.PlatformProvider

Comment: just ignore this error message! i got it too,but my authentication works fine.

Comment: I cannot ignore it because the authentication won't launch!!! Every time I press the button Logcat returns this message and then nothing happens.

Comment: This is a piece of working code by the way...

Comment: That is why I think the error message has something to do with my authentication not working fine.

Comment: Did your partner give you an apk, or code? If code, are you signing it yourself? And if so, did you add your key hash to the app settings on the app dashboard?

Comment: I'm currently walking through the code with my partner... Hopefully I'm not doing anything stupid.

Comment: The code works when the official Facebook app is present, but I'm pretty sure having the fb app installed in not required for the code to work... I would still like some input.

Comment: Would love to know if you got this to work. I'm experiencing it after updating a tablet without the Facebook app to KitKat 4.4 - I assume I've just got to update it to the latest Facebook SDK? You'd think it would handle this error by prompting the user to install the app!

Comment: Hey, sorry I didn't notice your comment. I think the message means that there's no Facebook app installed on the phone(and thus the authentication is not launching). I installed the fb app and everything works. However, I'm pretty sure that this should work regardless of whether the app is installed or not...

Comment: Well regarding if the app or installed or not, you can filter whether it's installed by using the FacebookDialog.canPresentShareDialog(this,FacebookDialog.ShareDialogFeature.SHARE_DIALOG) else use WebDialog